# How to get the title of data being passed between screen in react native?

Tags: react-native

Parent Class

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Child', {
    something: 'Some Value',
});
```

Child Class

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.something // outputs "Some Value"
```

But I want to get 'something' as a `String` to compare it in an if statement.
How should I do that?

Comment: it returns a string value. you can check that using ```typeof(this.props.navigation.state.params.something)```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to access all navigation params names, you can do `const paramNames = Object.keys(this.props.navigation.state.params)` which will be an array like `['something', 'anotherParam', 'andAnotherParam']`. If there is only one param passed, you can, respectively, get it's name with `paramNames[0]`